# Job to process a ssas Tabular model is failing even after having enough memory

Tags: ssas-tabular

I am trying to process the SSAS tabular model in process full mode. I have got 64GB RAM. But when I am try to process the tabular model by sql server agent its failing after the memory consumption by ssas for about 16GB even though there is enough memory to process.

When I try to process the ssas tab data model manually sometimes it is working fine but some times it is failing. The RAM usage was around 16GB and then it fails.

Below is the error for your refernce.

Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. .  The step failed.

can some body let me know if I has to make any changes/any settings to resolve the issue.

Comment: error msg: The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application. If using a 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" /><Error ErrorCode="3240034310" Description="The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services"

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Maximum memory utilized per tabular instance of Analysis Services is 16GB for SQL Server Standard Edition. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016

You could try to partial process the Cube in multiple steps to get a full process, this tends to utilize less RAM at once and keeps the total below 16GB.